# float(s) lost? How do I debug that?

Tags: floats

I get this error in one case, but not in another - this works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

\newfloat{defn}{thp}{def}[section]
\floatname{defn}{Definition}
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section]
\floatname{diag}{Diagram}

\begin{document}
    \begin{defn}[H]
        \begin{mydef}
            \caption{Exponentiation in a category}
            \label{def:ExponentiationInCategory}
            A category $\mathcal{C}$ has \textit{exponentiation} if $\forall a, b \in \mathcal{C}$ there is an object $b^a \in \mathcal{C}$ and an \textit{evaluation arrow} $ev \colon b^a \times a \rightarrow b$, such that $\forall c, (g \colon c \times a \rightarrow b) \in \mathcal{C}$, there is a unique arrow $\hat{g} \colon c \rightarrow b^a$, so the following commutes, ie there is a unique $\hat{g}$, so $ev \circ (\hat{g} \times 1_a) = g$:
            \begin{diag}[H]
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (baxa) at (0,2) {$b^a \times a$};
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (b) at (2,1) {$b$};
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (cxa) at (0,0) {$c \times a$};
                \draw[-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (baxa) to node [above=4pt] {$ev$} (b);
                \draw[-stealth, dashed, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (cxa) to node [left=4pt] {$\hat{g} \times 1_a$} (baxa);
                \draw[-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (cxa) to node [below=4pt] {$g$} (b);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Exponention in a category, $\mathcal{C}$}
                \label{dia:ExponentiationInCategory}
            \end{diag}
        \end{mydef}
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

However, this fails:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

\newfloat{defn}{thp}{def}[section]
\floatname{defn}{Definition}
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section]
\floatname{diag}{Diagram}

\begin{document}
    \begin{defn}[H]
        \begin{mydef}
            \caption{Co-limit}
            \label{def:CoLimit}
            A co-cone for a diagram $D$ with objects $d_i, ...$, consists of an object $c$, and arrows $f_i \colon d_i \rightarrow c$. A co-limit for $D$ is a co-cone, such that for any other co-cone $f^{\prime}_i \colon d_i \rightarrow c^{\prime}$, there is exactly one arrow $f \colon c \rightarrow c^{\prime}$ that makes the following diagram commute:
            \begin{diag}
                \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (di) at (1,2) {$d_i$};
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (c1) at (0,0) {$c$};
                \node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt] (c2) at (2,0) {$c^{\prime}$};
                \draw[-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (di) to node [above left=4pt] {$f_i$} (c1);
                \draw[-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (di) to node [above right=4pt] {$f^{\prime}_i$} (c2);
                \draw[-stealth, dashed, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (c1) to node [below=4pt] {$f$} (c2);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{Colimit}
                \label{dia:Colimit}
            \end{diag}
        \end{mydef}
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

with the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.45 \end{document}
```

What is the difference - I can't spot it?

Comment: In the second example, you use `diag` inside of `defn`. Since you define `diag`as well as `defn` as floating environments, this can't work, since you can't nest floats.

Comment: But I do that in the first example too, don't I? That's why I'm confused

Comment: The difference is that you use `\begin{diag}[H]` in the first example, while you use `\begin{diag}` in the second.

Comment: `[H]` makes the environment a non-float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A float environment marks its content as something that is *not* in the main document flow and may be re-inserted into the document at a different place, to avoid bad white space at page breaks.

They must always be used at the top level on the main page, you can not use a float inside any kind of box, and in particular not inside the box from an outer float environment.

The `[H]` option from the float package redefines the environment as a box at the current position that does not float and is not removed from the main document flow. As such it is not subject to the restrictions on where a float may be placed and can never generate a floats lost error.

Comment: You were right, of course. Thanks a lot!